# Pebble tutorial: "pebble build" and "pebble install" throwing errors on Arch machine

Tags: compiler-errors, archlinux, pebble-sdk

I'm having some trouble getting the super basic [Pebble tutorial](http://developer.getpebble.com/getting-started/watchface-tutorial/part1/) to work correctly. After following the steps in this tutorial, I get to the `pebble build` part and get a message after

> 'build' finished successfully

That message is

> [INFO    ] "<"Command '/usr/bin/arm-none-ea...(28 more)' call_args {'bg': False, 'timeo...(477 more)">": starting process

(Quotations before and after the < and > don't really exist in the message)

So although this is not an error message per se, I'm not sure why it's being displayed or how to check more of the information (documentation seems to be lacking here). The real problem is once I get to `pebble install`, I get an actual error message of

> [ERROR   ] global name 'traceEnabled' is not defined

Searching the internet gives no relevant information. Everything is about generic "not a global function" errors. Has anyone come across this problem in the past?

I'm running on an Arch Linux machine and installed the Pebble SDK through the AUR database. Not sure if that is related at all.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest SDK (currently 3.2) should fix your issues.

http://developer.pebble.com/sdk/install/linux/

Comment: thank you for the response. I haven't tried installing the current (3.2) SDK yet. However, I'm not sure this is going to fix my issue. If I'm not mistaken, SDK 3.2 does not work on the original Pebble watches ATM? I was specifically trying to install SDK 2.9 because I do not own the Pebble Time yet and thus cannot use any apps/watchfaces developed under SDK 3.2. Is there a way to fix this error in SDK 2.9? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually SDK 3.2 supports all Pebble watches.